# To put a name at the top of a dropdown

Tags: java, comparator

```
List<PropertySelectorHelper> SelectorsByHotel = 
  fetchSelectorsByHotel(properties,category);
List<PropertySelectorHelper> SelectorsByCountry = 
  filterSelectorsByCountry(SelectorsByHotel);
PropertyDataHelper.setSelectorsByCountry(SelectorsByCountry);

// how to add it here
```

This is my code.i get a sorted list of country names using this.Now i want to give any 1 particular country a priority at the top.
till now i am doing good..all i need now is to give 1 particular country a priority at the top.It should come first.i have sorted using a comparator but cannot add the logic there because it is being called by other files too.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have access to a machine right now to test and paste my code but here is what I would do :

1. Get a list of Countries from wherever you get right now.
2. Before sending the list of countries to the comparator, remove the preferred country from the list.
3. Send the updated list(without the preferred country) to the comparator for sorting
4. Once you get back the sorted list, add the preferred country to the top of the sorted list.

Let me know if you have any questions...

Hope this helps.

Comment: This would certainly work.But i want it to be generic. i would rather prefer coding 2 comparators and call  fetchSelectorsByHotel() and filterSelectorsByCountry() separately and add logic to display a particular country at the top in the filterSelectorsByCountry() comparator..what say?

Comment: You probably don't need two comparators but you could make the steps I suggested more generic by having a common method( takes in original list and a list of objects to be separated) that does the separation of the preferred objects and let the existing comparator code still do the job it is doing currently. I believe there is a framework - pls look at Apache Commons Collections that has helpers for this. http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CDsQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcommons.apache.org%2Fcollections%2F&ei=zOtyT-nMCM7PgAe83MXhCQ&usg=AFQjCNFNFkQB3JDycqnR7_4Buks4fAE58w